# Upquote and gensymb weird warnings

Tags: packages, warnings

I'm currently cleaning up my packages, and I've come across the two packages
`\usepackage{upquote}` and `\usepackage{gensymb}` where, for some reason I can't understand, `gensymb` is dependent on `upquote`

I'm wondering what, in `upquote`, is used by `gensymb`.

When I load `\usepackage{gensymb}` with `\usepackage{upquote}` there are no warnings or errors, but if I only load `\usepackage{gensymb}` (wihout `upquote`) the following warnings appear:

> Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.
>
> Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

I can't find anything in the two documentations, as to why..:

http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/was/gensymb.pdf
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/upquote/upquote.pdf

Can someone elaborate as to why these warnings appear?

Comment: This warning occurs, if you don't load `textcomp` (see documentation of `gensymb` pp. 1-2) and `upquote` loads `textcomp`, so the warning disappears

Comment: @DG' Doesn’t the LaTeX kernel define all the symbols from `textcomp` these days?

Comment: @DG' How do I load `textcomp` without `upquote` ?

Comment: @Davislor - `gensymb` is pretty old (2003) and checks only if  `textcomp` is loaded

Comment: @L.Nielsen - `\usepackage{textcomp}`

Comment: I'd suspect that [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) would be a good replacement for `gensymb`

Comment: Do you really need `gensymb` to begin with?